# What is the identity matrix for a reflection across the $y=-2$ line?

Tags: matrices

I am fairly familiar with how to multiply matrices and add/subtract them. This particular question, however, I am not sure about. How can I find the identity matrix whilst preserving congruence? Please explain.

Comment: Identity matrix is usually the matrix that makes no change to any vector when multiplying with it. Maybe you mean something else?

Comment: Reflection across $y=-2$ does not map zero vector to zero vector, so it is not linear map.

Comment: sometimes called affine...

Comment: It is a linear map, just not over $R^2$.

Comment: I guess that you are looking for the reflection matrix (with $\text{det}=-1$) which transforms a point $(x,y)$ to $(x,y+2)$ if $y<2$ and takes $(x,y)$ to $(x,y-2)$ if $y>2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to construct it what you are asking for. We first need knowledge of what this block does on a vector:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&a\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

So lets try it.

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&a\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}v_1+a\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

So the block is an **adder**.

In the same way the following matrix will add 2*third element to second element:
$$M_{A} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&2\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$

So we pad our vector with a 1 for third position:

\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\1\end{bmatrix}

Now the matrix for reflection $y$ axis:

$$M_R = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

And a last to move back into place:

$${M_{A}}^{-1} = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&-2\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$

All together:

$$ {M_A}^{-1} M_R M_A = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&-2\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&0\\0&1&2\\0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$